# Prevent Multiple Firing of Script on Scroll

Tags: jquery, hover, delay, settimeout, wait

I've got a list of spans, with 'meta-data' stored in the alt tag. When the user hovers over the span, for a full second, the alt tag information is appended to a different element, to be read.

My issue, is that if I quickly scroll across a number of spans, the script fires multiple times; so setTimeout() is pointless, since they all fire eventually and I get all of those alts appended, versus just the one that was hovered on for the full second.

```
var target;
$("#LIST span").live('hover', function(){
    target = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
        getALT = target.attr('alt');
        $(document).showALT();
    }, 1000);
});

jQuery.fn.showALT = function(){
    $("#tell2").append('X ')
    $(".Show_Info").attr('src', getALT);
}
```

The above is clearly flawed, and I know why, as stated above. I'm not sure how to accomplish what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clear it before use.

```
var target;
var timeO;
$("#LIST span").live('hover', function(){
    target = $(this);
    clearTimeout(timeO);
    timeO = setTimeout(function() {
        getALT = target.attr('alt');
        $(document).showALT();
    }, 1000);
});

jQuery.fn.showALT = function(){
    $("#tell2").append('X ')
    $(".Show_Info").attr('src', getALT);
}
```

P.S: you can use also: `function showALT(){` instead of: `jQuery.fn.showALT = function(){`

PS2: if you use jQ 7+ than `.live()` method is deprecated. Use `.on()` instead like:

`$("#LIST").on('hover','span', function(){`